# Verificando se o valor da coluna do banco de dados contem apenas números no select

Tags: sql, oracle, select

Preciso descobrir se o valor de uma determinada coluna do banco de dados contem apenas números no próprio select, pois se o mesmo for numérico, preciso apresentar o valor de outra coluna.

Utilizo um banco de dados ORACLE.

Alguém poderia me ajudar com esse problema?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Galera, consegui resolver usando o seguinte:

```
SELECT 
LENGTH(TRIM(TRANSLATE(TABELA.MEU_CAMPO_A_TESTAR, '0123456789',' '))) TESTE
FROM DUAL;
```

Se o TESTE retornar null, o campo contem apenas números.

Com isso fiz o seguinte CASE para buscar a informação de uma ou de outra coluna conforme o teste.

```
CASE WHEN ( LENGTH(TRIM(TRANSLATE(TABELA.MEU_CAMPO_A_TESTAR, '0123456789',' '))) IS NULL ) THEN TABELA.CAMPO_CASO_NUMERICO ELSE TABELA.MEU_CAMPO_A_TESTAR END AS CAMPO_APRESENTADO
```

Foi assim que resolvi meu problema.

Espero que ajude a quem procure alguma solução parecida.